# Literal Values from Database to RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals, radiobuttonlist

I have a database with MCQ which i query and fill a datatable with. My problem is with displaying.
I'm using this

```
Rbloptions.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(dt.Rows[RowNo]["Distractor1"].ToString(), dt.Rows[RowNo]["Distractor1"].ToString()));
```

If the value is mark up for example, i get all sorts of craziness e.g. the value is not displayed, parts of the words in the value are displayed etc.  How can i ensure that the radio button item uses the literal value.

Environment:
VS 2012
C#
asp.net 4.5

Comment: Have you tried html encoding the value?

Comment: What kinds of values are in `Distractor1`?

Comment: @michael, values like <strong>, <link> <br> etc.

Comment: @Brad, Would you guide me on how to do that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing this to get those values in there:

```
var val = HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(dt.Rows[RowNo]["Distractor1"].ToString());
Rbloptions.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(val, val));
```

That will encode those values before setting them.

Comment: @BradM, you're right. `HtmlEncode` is probably a better method.